# JsonPath : filter by value in array to get specific value

Tags: json, xpath, expression, jsonpath

I'm trying to filter by value an array in my Json with Jsonpath. I want to get the locationLegalName of the location in the JSON below.

For instance, I have a code CC024 and i need to compare with this json and where the location code is matching i want to extract the locationLegalName. Here in this case it will be Hotel Punta Cana.

Similarly, another example, I have a code CC021 and for that output will be Restaurant Punta Cana.

Can anyone help me with jsonPath?

```
[    
    {
        "propertyId": 171
        "locations": [
            {
                "locationId": 362,
                "locationCode": "CC001",
                "locationLegalName": "Hotel Atlantic City",
                "locationLongName": "Hotel Atlantic City",
                "locationShortName": "Hotel Atlantic City"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "propertyId": 174,
        "locations": [
            {
                "locationId": 435,
                "locationCode": "CC021",
                "locationLegalName": "Restaurant Punta Cana",
                "locationLongName": "Restaurant Punta Cana",
                "locationShortName": "Restaurant Punta Cana"
            },
            {
                "locationId": 436,
                "locationCode": "CC024",
                "locationLegalName": "Hotel Punta Cana",
                "locationLongName": "Hotel Punta Cana",
                "locationShortName": "Hotel Punta Cana"
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

I tried couple of jsonPath expressions but unable to write anything.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and how that's not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is gather all of the locations first using a recursive descent operator `..locations`.  Then it's pretty simple to filter through those to isolate the one you want.

```
$..locations[?@.locationCode=='CC021'].locationLegalName
```

Broken out:

```
$..locations                                             (1)
            [?@.locationCode=='CC021']                   (2)
                                      .locationLegalName (3)
```

1. Get all of the locations.  The result of this is a collection of arrays.
2. Search through each of the arrays for items with `locationCode == 'CC021'`.  The result here is a collection of objects.
3. Get `locationLegalName` of any that are returned.  The result here is a collection of strings.

This can be tested on https://json-everything.net/json-path (my playground).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need one more favor. The expression that you shared is giving me output like this:
[
  "Hotel Atlantic City"
]

Is there any way that I can get only the string inside it? Like the output I want is: "Hotel Atlantic City"

Comment: JSON Path is a query. It's going to return a collection of matches.  It's likely the lib you're using is rendering that as a JSON array.  You can pull that out in code if you need.